# Adding new field to the document in the array of documents

Tags: mongodb

I have mongo document like that:

```
{                                                                                                                               
  "_id" : ObjectId("61b4cd63465cd7ace1e12341"),                                                                           
  "artist" : "Short",                                                                                                     
  "album" : "Track",                                                                                                      
  "tracks" : [                                                                                                                    
          {                                                                                                                              
             "title" : "100m",                                                                                                       
             "length" : 10                                                                                                   
          },                                                                                                                      
          {                                                                                                                               
             "title" : "200m",                                                                                                       
             "length" : 20,                                                                                                          
             "guest" : "Big Bad"                                                                                             
          }                                                                                                               
     ]                                                                                                               
}
```

I'm trying to add field `quest` to the `tracks` array with title 100m.
So that a document looks like that:

```
{                                                                                                                               
  "_id" : ObjectId("61b4cd63465cd7ace1e12341"),                                                                           
  "artist" : "Short",                                                                                                     
  "album" : "Track",                                                                                                      
  "tracks" : [                                                                                                                    
          {                                                                                                                              
             "title" : "100m",                                                                                                       
             "length" : 10,
             "guest": : "John Travolta"                                                                                                   
          },                                                                                                                      
          {                                                                                                                               
             "title" : "200m",                                                                                                       
             "length" : 20,                                                                                                          
             "guest" : "Big Bad"                                                                                             
          }                                                                                                               
     ]                                                                                                               
}
```

I was tryin got achive that using `db.collection.update` and `$set`, but no good results.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [positional operator `$`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) like this:

```
db.collection.update({
  "tracks.title": "100m"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "tracks.$.guest": "John Travolta"
  }
})
```

This query tells to mongo "For the element into the `tracks` array where the `title` is `100m`, insert the field `guest` with value `John Travolta`". And all of this using `$` and the query stage `"tracks.title": "100m"`

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dHOAX7zs50R)